# Raspberry pi Zero or 1B+ USB boot not working

Tags: usb, boot-issues, root

I have been trying to move root file system to external disk for a few weeks and I came across one problem. My disk was not mounting. No matter what would I do, my screen always hanged on `"Waiting for root device PARTUUID=..."`
Finally I gave up when I came across usb-boot script from this link https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=196778. After executing script i had my root and boot on external hdd disk. Then i formated sd card to fat32 partition and copied bootcode.bin file plus timeout file. And then I came across new problem. My Pi no matter if I use B+ or zero v1.3 it just does not recognize the sd card. It acts like there is no sd card. I tried with to partitions one ext4 and one fat32 still nothing. I have been checking PARTUUID several times, i changed cmdline.txt and fstab during my "moving only root to usb" period. I just dont know what to do and it is really frustrating. My original topic showing every single step i took is here. Its not that long if You want to help please take a look, maybe you have any clue why this is happening. I dont care if i boot from usb or just use it as root file system, I just need it to be on usb. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=320508

Comment: this is a Q&A site, not a chat forum ... please ask a specific question

Comment: It is a specific question. I need some clue on what maybe wrong. Just reaching for help. Hate this place. Whenever i try to get an answer someone tries to teach me something unrelevant. I have seen many topics with no specific questions and no one closed them. Its not like the entire forum will colapse if I reach for some help.

Comment: You should post details here instead of forcing people to go elsewhere... Would also help if you add some formatting to your question